# PHP: Update query not update time in TIMESTAMP() format column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, timestamp

I am working on user online and offline status in php. My problem is that I need to update time in TIMESTAMP() column when user logged in. But here update query doesn't work. Can you please tell me that how to update it

```
$setLogged = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE user SET user_onlineStatus='" . time() . "'WHERE user_id='" . $user_id . "'");
```

Comment: You can simplify that by doing `"UPDATE user SET user_onlineStatus=NOW()"`

Comment: Thanks for the response. `time()` function is working perfectly but problem is in the update query

Comment: Well do as suggested `"UPDATE user SET user_onlineStatus=NOW() WHERE user_id='$user_id' "`

Comment: The only real reason I suggested using `now()` was that it makes the string concatenation unnecessary and that appears to be what you are struggling with.

Answer (score 2):

Error is here:

```
"'WHERE user_id='"
```

should be:

```
"' WHERE user_id='"
```

Also, if you encounter errors like this, when your query doesn't work, always print query with var_dump() and run it directly in command line.

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET user_onlineStatus='" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "' WHERE user_id='" . $user_id . "'";
// var_dump($sql)
$setLogged = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: Here is the value `string(64) "UPDATE user SET user_onlineStatus='1463336827'WHERE user_id='14'"` when I added `var_dump($sql)`

Comment: Now I have changed its format `TIMESTAMP()` to `TIME()`

Comment: Try this: `$sql = "UPDATE user SET user_onlineStatus='" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()) . "' WHERE user_id='" . $user_id . "'";`

Comment: time and timastamp fields require string in format 'Y-m-d H:i:s', and you are sending a number (user_onlineStatus='1463336827')

Comment: USE `NOW()` its so easy

Comment: @ImranHasan, TIME() s ok: `$sql = "UPDATE user SET user_onlineStatus='" . date('H:i:s') . "' WHERE user_id='" . $user_id . "'";`

Answer (score 0):

`'" . time() . "'` you're passing that as a string literal, it's a function.

```
UPDATE user SET user_onlineStatus = time() WHERE user_id='" . $user_id . "'
```

However, [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) returns as a Unix timestamp `1463338870` format, rather than `2016-05-15 19:01:39` which is why it's failing you here, seeing your `user_onlineStatus` column is a TIMESTAMP type.

Ideally, you would be better off using the "now" method of today's time and date, your column type should either be `DATE` or `DATETIME`. Sidenote: As noted, a TIMESTAMP type is also valid (as per RiggsFolly's comment below).

so

```
"UPDATE user SET user_onlineStatus = now() WHERE user_id='$user_id' ";
```

If it isn't either, then I suspect it to be VARCHAR which is a bad idea.

Reference on DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html

If none of those worked for you, then your `$user_id` may be failing and is unknown whether or not it contains a value.

Make sure it does have a value, so check for errors.

Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);  
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 

$setLogged = mysqli_query($conn, 

"UPDATE user SET user_onlineStatus = NOW() 
 WHERE user_id='" . $user_id . "' ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

---

**A few unknowns:**

- If you're using sessions. If so, make sure you started the session.
- The MySQL API to connect with. If you're using anything other than `mysqli_` to connect with, those different APIs do not intermix.

---

**Foonotes:**

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: @ImranHasan Right follow this advice if you wont follow mine

Comment: *Howdy Smokey* @RiggsFolly :-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly No not at all, thanks. I just thought I'd leave the quotes out of it ;-) we'll leave it at that.

Comment: `NOW()` shoudl also work if the datatype is a `TIMESTAMP`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have recently changed format to `TIME`. Which function should I use now

Comment: @ImranHasan Use `DATETIME` however your `TIMESTAMP` type https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html should have been ok. I've made a few edits to my answer therefore you would need to reload it. Details are in there as well as if your variable has a value or not. DATE only returns `YYYY-MM-DD` rather than DATETIME's `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.